# python can't break while loop when play audio with pygame-change

Tags: python, while-loop, pygame, keyboard, break

I tried something new to fit the code. Now when I press ctrl + s the audio really stops but when my personal assistant plays music again in the same run, the music does not stop as for the first time:

```
import glob
import os
import keyboard

os.environ['PYGAME_HIDE_SUPPORT_PROMPT'] = "hide"

import pygame
songs = glob.glob("C:\\Users\zivsi\Music\\*.mp3")
import random

song = random.choice(songs)

with open("song_choice.txt", "r") as file:
    read = file.read()

if (read == song):
    print("switch song")
    song = random.choice(songs)

song_name = song.replace("C:\\Users\zivsi\Music\\", "").replace(".mp3", "")
print("song: ", song_name)

pygame.mixer.init()

music = pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
pygame.mixer.music.play()

while (pygame.mixer_music.get_busy()):
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
    keyboard.add_hotkey("ctrl + s", lambda: pygame.mixer_music.stop())
```

# if i will press ctrl + s, the music will stop but it's working only once`

Comment: You can't use `break` in a different scope, no. `lambda`s are *functions*, so a different scope. Set a flag instead.

Comment: how to write flag in my code?

Comment: Any value you can alter from a function that your `while` loop can test for will do. Like `flags[0] = True`, with `flags` being a global list set to `[False]` (with possibly more values). Ugly, but it would work. Or an attribute on a global instance. Etc.

Comment: You don't want to have a function like keyboard.addhotkey inside your loop, as shown here.  It would be done outside the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `break` in a different scope, it *has* to be part of the loop suite itself (so nested inside a `while` or `for` statement). A `lambda` is a function, which is a different scope.

Because you want to break out of the loop asynchronously, you'll need some other way to communicate from the keyboard callback handler back to the main loop. In general computer engineering terms, you need some kind of [*synchronization primitive*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017507/definition-of-synchronization-primitive) to synchronize between different things that are happening at the same time, concurrently.

That is to say, you want to set some kind of *flag*, one that you can check in your `while` loop, so `while pygame.mixer_music.get_busy() and not keyboard_ctrl_s_flag:`. You can do this with any global value, and that'd *probably* be safe:

```
keyboard_ctrl_s_flag = False  

def control_s_handler():
    """Called when the keyboard combination CTRL-S is pressed"""
    global keyboard_ctrl_s_flag
    keyboard_ctrl_s_flag = True

keyboard.add_hotkey("ctrl + s", control_s_handler)
```

then you can use that in your loop:

```
# reset the flag to false, in case it was already set to true before
keyboard_ctrl_s_flag = False  
while pygame.mixer_music.get_busy() and not keyboard_ctrl_s_flag:
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
```

I say this *probably* is safe, because I'm not quite sure how PyGame is running its event handling loop.  Given that you also used `pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)` in your loop makes me think that the event loop probably waits for your Python code to return control before doing other things.

The next time that the user then uses `CTRL-S`, the `control_s_handler()` callback is called, `keyboard_ctrl_s_flag` is set to `True`, and when control returns to the `while` loop (because `pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)` returned control to your Python code) the `while` loop exits even if `pygame.mixer_music.get_busy()` is still true.

Comment: side note: the code in the question does not use pygame's event queue, which needs a window to work.

Comment: @sloth: for some reason I thought the `keyboard` module used was part of PyGame, I should have looked closer.